# Silex : how to set the value of a datetime input in the widget

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, silex, formbuilder

I built a form with a datetime input on Silex, using the FormBuilderInterface. The validation works perfectly, but when the datas are loaded to rebuild the form and fill in the inputs' values, the datetime's stays empty. I've been doing some researches but nothing so far so here I am.

The form is built in a class called EventType and fills an Event object. The $dateOfEvent property's setter asks for a \DateTime object and the getter returns $dateOfEvent without formatting it.

Here is what the EventType's builder's date of event part looks like :

```
->add('dateOfEvent', 'datetime', array(
                'label' => 'Date of the event',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'input' => 'datetime',
                ))
```

If the Event object is already filled, all the inputs' values of the form are filled, except for the file input (which is normal) and the datetime input (which is not normal).

Here is [a screen](http://prntscr.com/990kkr) of what it looks like.

Comment: what is the type of date filed

Comment: It's a DateTime object. It is filled using the JS plugin bootstrap-datetimepicker but I don't think it changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

you should fix the name of the form field, it should match the property's:

```
->add('event', 'datetime', array(
            'label' => 'Date of the event',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'input' => 'datetime',
            ))
```

Comment: Actually, my problem is that I want to fill the value with the Event's date of event property. I don't especially want to put a default value.

Comment: Then you should fix the name of the form field, it should match the property's!

Comment: Unfortunately, it already does. The property is called $dateOfEvent.

Comment: It has a getter and a setter?

Comment: Indeed. The setter asks for a \DateTime object.